# Stuck on Infinite Loop, Sublimetext3 MAC

Tags: macos, loops, sublimetext3

I had an infinite loop on sublime text 3. This caused immediate freezing so I couldn't edit or cancel with cmd c, etc. Upon reopening sublimetext3, it would auto run.

*note this issue wasn't possible to fix in Sublime due to packages including auto-save and the option selected to open files upon running Sublime.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using terminal or downloading packages, I found an easy way to edit the text with the bad loop.

on mac -> finder --> go to folder(drop down) --> ~/Library/ --> application support--> sublime text 3 --> packages --> user --> find the file --> open with text editor --> delete lines with infinite loop --> actions --> save. – Learner just now   edit